# Laravel Sms Configuration

Tags: laravel, configuration, sms

We using to private message service. I want send sms notification to message received person.

I searched but couldn't find. But I could do this much maybe wrong maybe right.

Sometimes the page gave a complete data error

I Understand may have given the recipient wrong

I do this code ;

```
    if(config('config.task_sms_notification')){
        $message = 'Merhaba, Suit 13\'de Tarafiniza Yeni Mesaj Gonderildi. Gonderen: '.$request->input('to_user_id');
        $user = $new_message->to_user_id;
            if($user->Profile->mobile)
            $user->notify(new TaskNotification($message,$task));
        }
    }
```

Private message service codes;

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('feature_available:enable_message');
}

public function validateLiveMessage($type,$value){
    $message = Message::where($type,'=',$value)->where(function($query) {
        $query->where(function($query1){
            $query1->where('from_user_id','=',\Auth::user()->id)
            ->where('delete_sender','=','0');
        })->orWhere(function($query2){
            $query2->where('to_user_id','=',\Auth::user()->id)
            ->where('delete_receiver','=','0');
        });
    })->first();
    return ($message) ? : 0;
}

public function validateDeleteMessage($type,$value){
    $message = Message::where($type,'=',$value)->where(function($query) {
        $query->where(function($query1){
            $query1->where('from_user_id','=',\Auth::user()->id)
            ->where('delete_sender','=','1');
        })->orWhere(function($query2){
            $query2->where('to_user_id','=',\Auth::user()->id)
            ->where('delete_receiver','=','1');
        });
    })->first();
    return ($message) ? : 0;
}

public function index(){

    $table_data['inbox-table'] = array(
        'source' => 'message/inbox',
        'title' => 'Inbox',
        'id' => 'inbox_table',
        'data' => array(
            trans('messages.option'),
            trans('messages.from'),
            trans('messages.subject'),
            trans('messages.date_time'),
            ''
            )
        );

    $table_data['sent-table'] = array(
        'source' => 'message/sent',
        'title' => 'Sent',
        'id' => 'sent_table',
        'data' => array(
            trans('messages.option'),
            trans('messages.to'),
            trans('messages.subject'),
            trans('messages.date_time'),
            ''
            )
        );

    $table_data['starred-table'] = array(
        'source' => 'message/starred',
        'title' => 'Starred',
        'id' => 'starred_table',
        'data' => array(
            trans('messages.option'),
            '',
            trans('messages.subject'),
            trans('messages.date_time'),
            ''
            )
        );

    $table_data['trash-table'] = array(
        'source' => 'message/trash',
        'title' => 'Trash',
        'id' => 'trash_table',
        'data' => array(
            trans('messages.option'),
            '',
            trans('messages.subject'),
            trans('messages.date_time'),
            ''
            )
        );

    $users = \App\User::where('id','!=',\Auth::user()->id)->get()->pluck('full_name','id')->all();
    $messages = Message::whereToUserId(\Auth::user()->id)
        ->whereDeleteReceiver('0')->whereNull('reply_id')
        ->get();
    $count_inbox = count($messages);

    $assets = ['summernote','datatable'];
    $menu = 'message';

    return view('message.index',compact('users','count_inbox','assets','menu','table_data'));
}

public function starred(Request $request){

    $message = $this->validateLiveMessage('token',$request->input('token'));

    if(!$message)
        return response()->json(['message' => trans('messages.invalid_link'), 'status' => 'error']);

    if(\Auth::user()->id == $message->from_user_id)
        $message->is_starred_sender = ($message->is_starred_sender) ? 0 : 1;
    else
        $message->is_starred_receiver = ($message->is_starred_receiver) ? 0 : 1;
    $message->save();

    return response()->json(['status' => 'success']);
}

public function lists($type,Request $request){

    if($type == 'inbox')
        $inbox_message = Message::whereToUserId(\Auth::user()->id)
            ->select(\DB::raw('reply_id'))
            ->whereDeleteReceiver(0)
            ->whereNotNull('reply_id')
            ->groupBy('reply_id')
            ->get()
            ->pluck('reply_id')
            ->all();
    elseif($type == 'sent')
        $sent_message = Message::whereFromUserId(\Auth::user()->id)
            ->select(\DB::raw('reply_id'))
            ->whereDeleteSender(0)
            ->whereNotNull('reply_id')
            ->groupBy('reply_id')
            ->get()
            ->pluck('reply_id')
            ->all();

    if($type == 'sent')
        $messages = Message::where(function($query) use($sent_message){
            $query->where(function($query1) use($sent_message){
                $query1->where('from_user_id','=',\Auth::user()->id)
                ->where('delete_sender','=','0')
                ->whereNull('reply_id');
            })->orWhereIn('id',$sent_message);
        })->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();
    elseif($type == 'inbox')
        $messages = Message::where(function($query) use($inbox_message){
            $query->where(function($query1) use($inbox_message){
                $query1->where('to_user_id','=',\Auth::user()->id)
                ->where('delete_receiver','=','0')
                ->whereNull('reply_id');
            })->orWhereIn('id',$inbox_message);
        })->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();
    elseif($type == 'starred')
        $messages = Message::where(function($query){
            $query->where(function($query1){
                $query1->where('from_user_id','=',\Auth::user()->id)
                ->where('delete_sender','=',0)
                ->where('is_starred_sender','=',1);
            })->orWhere(function($query2){
                $query2->where('to_user_id','=',\Auth::user()->id)
                ->where('delete_receiver','=',0)
                ->where('is_starred_receiver','=',1);
            });
        })->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();
    elseif($type == 'trash')
        $messages = Message::where(function($query){
            $query->where(function($query1){
                $query1->where('from_user_id','=',\Auth::user()->id)
                ->where('delete_sender','=',1);
            })->orWhere(function($query2){
                $query2->where('to_user_id','=',\Auth::user()->id)
                ->where('delete_receiver','=',1);
            });
        })->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();

    $rows=array();
    foreach($messages as $message){

        $starred = 0;
        if(\Auth::user()->id == $message->from_user_id)
            $starred = ($message->is_starred_sender) ? 1 : 0;
        else
            $starred = ($message->is_starred_receiver) ? 1 : 0;

        $option = (($type != 'trash') ? '<div class="btn-group btn-group-xs"><a href="/message/'.$message->token.'" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" data-toggle="tooltip" title="'.trans('messages.view').'"> <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>' : '').
            (($type != 'trash') ? '<a href="#" data-source="/message/starred" data-extra="&token='.$message->token.'" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" data-ajax="1"> <i class="fa fa-'.($starred ? 'star starred' : 'star-o').'"></i></a>' : '').
            (($type == 'trash') ? '<a href="#" data-source="/message/restore" data-extra="&token='.$message->token.'" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" data-ajax="1"> <i class="fa fa-retweet" data-toggle="tooltip" data-title="'.trans('messages.restore').'"></i></a>' : '').
            (($type != 'trash') ? delete_form(['message.trash',$message->id]) : delete_form(['message.destroy',$message->id])).'</div>';

            $source = (\Auth::user()->id == $message->from_user_id) ? $message->UserTo->full_name : $message->UserFrom->full_name;

            if($type == 'starred' || $type == 'trash')
                $source .= (\Auth::user()->id == $message->from_user_id) ? ' <span class="label label-success">Sent</span>' : ' <span class="label label-info">Inbox</span>';

            $unread = 0;
            if($type == 'inbox' && ((!$message->is_read && $message->to_user_id == \Auth::user()->id) || ($message->Replies->where('to_user_id','=',\Auth::user()->id)->where('is_read','=',0)->count())))
                $unread = 1;

            if($message->Replies->count() && ($type == 'inbox' || $type == 'sent'))
                $source .= ' ('.(($message->Replies->where('to_user_id','=',\Auth::user()->id)->where('delete_receiver','=',0)->count())+($message->Replies->where('from_user_id','=',\Auth::user()->id)->where('delete_sender','=',0)->count())+1).')';

            if($type == 'trash' && $message->reply_id != null && (($message->Reply->to_user_id == \Auth::user()->id && $message->Reply->delete_receiver == 1) || ($message->Reply->from_user_id == \Auth::user()->id && $message->Reply->delete_sender == 1)))
                $show = 0;
            else
                $show = 1;

            if($show)
                $rows[] = array('<div class="btn-group btn-group-xs">'.$option.'</div>', 
                    ($unread) ? ('<strong>'.$source.'</strong>') : $source,
                    ($unread) ? ('<strong>'.$message->subject.'</strong>') : $message->subject,
                    ($unread) ? ('<strong>'.showDateTime($message->created_at).'</strong>') : showDateTime($message->created_at),
                    ($message->attachments) ? '<i class="fa fa-paperclip"></i>' : ''
                );  
    }
    $list['aaData'] = $rows;
    return json_encode($list);
}

public function forward($token){

    $message = $this->validateLiveMessage('token',$token);

    if(!$message)
        return view('global.error',['message' => trans('messages.permission_denied')]);

    \App\Upload::whereModule('message')->whereModuleId($message->id)->whereStatus(1)->update(['is_temp_delete' => 0]);

    $uploads = \App\Upload::whereModule('message')->whereModuleId($message->id)->whereStatus(1)->get();

    $users = \App\User::where('id','!=',\Auth::user()->id)->get()->pluck('full_name','id')->all();
    return view('message.forward',compact('message','users','uploads'));
}

public function postForward(Request $request, $token){

    $message = $this->validateLiveMessage('token',$token);

    if(!$message)
        return response()->json(['message' => trans('messages.invalid_link'), 'status' => 'error']);

    $validation = Validator::make($request->all(),[
        'to_user_id' => 'required',
        'subject' => 'required'
    ]);
    $friendly_name = array('to_user_id' => 'receiver');
    $validation->setAttributeNames($friendly_name); 

    if($validation->fails())
        return response()->json(['message' => $validation->messages()->first(), 'status' => 'error']);

    $existing_upload = \App\Upload::whereModule('message')->whereModuleId($message->id)->whereIsTempDelete(0)->count();

    $new_upload_count = 0;
    foreach($request->input('upload_key') as $upload_key)
        $new_upload_count += \App\Upload::whereModule('message')->whereUploadKey($upload_key)->count();

    if($existing_upload + $new_upload_count > config('constant.max_file_allowed.message'))
        return response()->json(['message' => trans('messages.max_file_allowed',['attribute' => config('constant.max_file_allowed.message')]),'status' => 'error']);

    $new_message = new Message;
    $new_message->subject = $request->input('subject');
    $new_message->body = clean($request->input('body'),'custom');
    $new_message->attachments = $message->attachments;
    $new_message->to_user_id = $request->input('to_user_id');
    $new_message->from_user_id = \Auth::user()->id;
    $new_message->token = randomString(30);
    $new_message->attachments = ($existing_upload + $new_upload_count) ? 1 : 0;
    $new_message->save();

    $existing_uploads = \App\Upload::whereModule('message')->whereModuleId($message->id)->whereStatus(1)->whereIsTempDelete(0)->get();
    foreach($existing_uploads as $existing_upload){
        $new_upload_key = randomString(40);
        $new_upload = new \App\Upload;
        $new_upload->user_id = \Auth::user()->id;
        $new_upload->module = 'message';
        $new_upload->user_filename = $existing_upload->user_filename;
        $upload_attachment = explode('.',$existing_upload->attachments);
        $new_upload->attachments = str_random(50).'.'.$upload_attachment[1];
        $new_upload->module_id = $new_message->id;
        $new_upload->upload_key = $new_upload_key;
        $new_upload->status = 1;
        $new_upload->save();
        \Storage::copy('attachments/'.$existing_upload->attachments, 'attachments/'.$new_upload->attachments);
    }

    foreach($request->input('upload_key') as $upload_key){
        $uploads = \App\Upload::whereModule('message')->whereUploadKey($upload_key)->get();
        $new_upload_key = randomString(40);
        foreach($uploads as $upload){
            $upload->module_id = $new_message->id;
            $upload->status = 1;
            $upload->save();
            \Storage::move('temp_attachments/'.$upload->attachments, 'attachments/'.$upload->attachments);
        }
    }

    \App\Upload::whereModule('message')->whereModuleId($message->id)->whereStatus(1)->whereIsTempDelete(1)->update(['is_temp_delete' => 0]);

    $this->logActivity(['module' => 'message','module_id' => $new_message->id,'activity' => 'forwarded']);

    return response()->json(['message' => trans('messages.message').' '.trans('messages.sent'), 'status' => 'success']);
}

public function load(Request $request){

    $message = $this->validateLiveMessage('token',$request->input('token'));

    if($message){
        $replies = Message::where('reply_id','=',$message->id)->where(function($query){
            $query->where(function($query1){
                $query1->where('to_user_id','=',\Auth::user()->id)->where('delete_receiver','=','0');
            })->orWhere(function($query2){
                $query2->where('from_user_id','=',\Auth::user()->id)->where('delete_sender','=','0');
            });
        })->get();
        return view('message.load',compact('message','replies'))->render();
    }
}

public function reply($id,Request $request){

    $message = $this->validateLiveMessage('id',$id);

    if(!$message)
        return response()->json(['message' => trans('messages.invalid_link'), 'status' => 'error']);

    $file_uploaded_count = \App\Upload::whereIn('upload_key',$request->input('upload_key'))->count();

    if($file_uploaded_count > config('constant.max_file_allowed.message'))
        return response()->json(['message' => trans('messages.max_file_allowed',['attribute' => config('constant.max_file_allowed.message')]),'status' => 'error']);

    $data = $request->all();

    $reply = new Message;
    $reply->fill($data);
    $reply->token = randomString(30);
    $reply->subject = 'Re: '.$message->subject;
    $reply->body = clean($request->input('body'),'custom');
    $reply->from_user_id = \Auth::user()->id;
    $reply->reply_id = $message->id;
    $reply->attachments = ($file_uploaded_count) ? 1 : 0;
    $reply->is_read = 0;
    $reply->to_user_id = ($message->from_user_id == \Auth::user()->id) ? $message->to_user_id : $message->from_user_id;
    $reply->save();

    foreach($request->input('upload_key') as $upload_key){
        $uploads = \App\Upload::whereModule('message')->whereUploadKey($upload_key)->get();
        foreach($uploads as $upload){
            $upload->module_id = $reply->id;
            $upload->status = 1;
            $upload->save();
            \Storage::move('temp_attachments/'.$upload->attachments, 'attachments/'.$upload->attachments);
        }
    }

    $this->logActivity(['module' => 'message','module_id' => $reply->id,'activity' => 'replied']);

    return response()->json(['message' => trans('messages.message').' '.trans('messages.sent'), 'status' => 'success']);
}

public function store(MessageRequest $request){

    $file_uploaded_count = \App\Upload::whereIn('upload_key',$request->input('upload_key'))->count();

    if($file_uploaded_count > config('constant.max_file_allowed.message'))
        return response()->json(['message' => trans('messages.max_file_allowed',['attribute' => config('constant.max_file_allowed.message')]),'status' => 'error']);

    $data = $request->all();

    $message = new Message;
    $message->fill($data);
    $message->token = randomString(30);
    $message->body = clean($request->input('body'),'custom');
    $message->from_user_id = \Auth::user()->id;
    $message->is_read = 0;
    $message->attachments = ($file_uploaded_count) ? 1 : 0;
    $message->save();

    foreach($request->input('upload_key') as $upload_key){
        $uploads = \App\Upload::whereModule('message')->whereUploadKey($upload_key)->get();
        foreach($uploads as $upload){
            $upload->module_id = $message->id;
            $upload->status = 1;
            $upload->save();
            \Storage::move('temp_attachments/'.$upload->attachments, 'attachments/'.$upload->attachments);
        }
    }

    $this->logActivity(['module' => 'message','module_id' => $message->id,'activity' => 'sent']);

    return response()->json(['message' => trans('messages.message').' '.trans('messages.sent'), 'status' => 'success']);
}

public function download($file){
    $upload = \App\Upload::whereAttachments($file)->whereModule('message')->whereStatus(1)->first();

    if(!$upload)
        return redirect('/message')->withErrors(trans('messages.invalid_link'));

    $message = Message::find($upload->module_id);

    if(!$message)
        return redirect('/message')->withErrors(trans('messages.invalid_link'));

    if($message->to_user_id != \Auth::user()->id && $message->from_user_id != \Auth::user()->id)
        return redirect('/message')->withErrors(trans('messages.permission_denied'));

    if(!\Storage::exists('attachments/'.$upload->attachments))
        return redirect('/message')->withErrors(trans('messages.file_not_found'));

    $download_path = storage_path().config('constant.storage_root').'attachments/'.$upload->attachments;

    return response()->download($download_path, $upload->user_filename);
}

public function view($token){

    $message = $this->validateLiveMessage('token',$token);

    if(!$message)
        return redirect('/message')->withErrors(trans('messages.invalid_link'));    

    if($message->Replies->count())
        Message::where('reply_id','=',$message->id)->where('to_user_id','=',\Auth::user()->id)->update(['is_read' => 1]);

    if($message->reply)
        return redirect('/message/'.$message->Reply->token);

    if(\Auth::user()->id == $message->to_user_id){
        $message->is_read = 1;
        $message->save();
    }

    $assets = ['summernote'];

    return view('message.view',compact('message','assets'));
}

public function trash($id,Request $request){

    $message = $this->validateLiveMessage('id',$id);

    if(!$message)
        return response()->json(['message' => trans('messages.invalid_link'), 'status' => 'error']);

    $this->logActivity(['module' => 'message','module_id' => $message->id,'activity' => 'trashed']);

    if($message->to_user_id == \Auth::user()->id)
        $message->delete_receiver = 1;
    else
        $message->delete_sender = 1;    
    $message->save();

    if($message->Replies->count()){
        $sender_messages = $message->Replies->where('from_user_id','=',\Auth::user()->id)->pluck('id');
        Message::whereIn('id',$sender_messages)->update(['delete_sender' => 1]);
        $receiver_messages = $message->Replies->where('to_user_id','=',\Auth::user()->id)->pluck('id');
        Message::whereIn('id',$receiver_messages)->update(['delete_receiver' => 1]);
    }

    return response()->json(['message' => trans('messages.message').' '.trans('messages.trashed'), 'status' => 'success']);
}

public function restore(Request $request){

    $message = $this->validateDeleteMessage('token',$request->input('token'));

    if(!$message)
        return response()->json(['message' => trans('messages.invalid_link'), 'status' => 'error']);

    if($message->reply_id != null && (($message->Reply->to_user_id == \Auth::user()->id && $message->Reply->delete_receiver > 0) || ($message->Reply->from_user_id == \Auth::user()->id && $message->Reply->delete_sender > 0)))
        return response()->json(['message' => trans('messages.invalid_link'), 'status' => 'error']);

    $this->logActivity(['module' => 'message','module_id' => $message->id,'activity' => 'restored']);

    if($message->to_user_id == \Auth::user()->id)
        $message->delete_receiver = 0;
    else
        $message->delete_sender = 0;    
    $message->save();

    if($message->Replies->count()){
        $sender_messages = $message->Replies->where('from_user_id','=',\Auth::user()->id)->pluck('id');
        Message::whereIn('id',$sender_messages)->update(['delete_sender' => 0]);
        $receiver_messages = $message->Replies->where('to_user_id','=',\Auth::user()->id)->pluck('id');
        Message::whereIn('id',$receiver_messages)->update(['delete_receiver' => 0]);
    }

    return response()->json(['message' => trans('messages.message').' '.trans('messages.restored'), 'status' => 'success']);
}

public function destroy($id,Request $request){

    $message = $this->validateDeleteMessage('id',$id);

    if(!$message)
        return response()->json(['message' => trans('messages.invalid_link'), 'status' => 'error']);

    if(getMode()){
        $uploads = \App\Upload::whereModule('message')->whereModuleId($message->id)->get();
        foreach($uploads as $upload)
            \Storage::delete('attachments/'.$upload->attachments);
        \App\Upload::whereModule('message')->whereModuleId($message->id)->delete();
    }

    $this->logActivity(['module' => 'message','module_id' => $message->id,'activity' => 'deleted']);

    if($message->to_user_id == \Auth::user()->id)
        $message->delete_receiver = 2;
    else
        $message->delete_sender = 2;    
    $message->save();

    if($message->Replies->count()){
        $sender_messages = $message->Replies->where('from_user_id','=',\Auth::user()->id)->pluck('id');
        Message::whereIn('id',$sender_messages)->update(['delete_sender' => 2]);
        $receiver_messages = $message->Replies->where('to_user_id','=',\Auth::user()->id)->pluck('id');
        Message::whereIn('id',$receiver_messages)->update(['delete_receiver' => 2]);
    }

    return response()->json(['message' => trans('messages.message').' '.trans('messages.deleted'), 'status' => 'success']);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Does this line

```
$user = $new_message->to_user_id;
```

Return the Eloquent Model of the User or just the ID ? Is it a relation ? If not, as in the next lines you seem to try to access a relation.

```
if($user->Profile->mobile)
```

It is a wild guess, but maybe you need to do something like this

```
$user = User::findOrFail($new_message->to_user_id);
```

or setup a relation in Message model to be able to get the User object

Comment: This line ; I need to user id.

$user = $new_message->to_user_id;

And this line ; I take to user's mobile number, and send to sms notification.

if($user->Profile->mobile)

Comment: If you need the user id to $user, then $user cannot be a Model that will return to you something when called like $user->Profile. It is just a number, not an object. In order to help you I think you should provide the error message in your original code.